# RecyclerView strange behavior after notifyItemRangeChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing some problems with `notifyItemRemoved` and `notifyItemRangeChanged`.
I have a `RecyclerView` which is populated by cards. Every card has its own button. I've implemented on `RecyclerView's` method `onBindViewHolder` an `OnClickListener` for the button. When pressed, I want the card to delete itself. I have the following code:

```
 holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {    
                mDataset.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), mDataset.size());                       
        }
    });
```

There is a strange behavior with deleting. The card I want to delete disappears for a short time then fastly reappears and if I try to press the delete button again, it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.
Did anyone experience anything like this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), mDataset.size());
```

Comment: @LuciBurcu in what way does this solution not work? The more specific your feedback, the more easily we can help.

Comment: @BenP. Removing the line does not change anything. It does the same strange thing

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem. I've set in ViewHolder the method setIsRecyclable to false and that causes the Recycler to not properly animate the removal. Thanks for any comments and sorry for my dumb question